# Can not use a vector in boost/unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost

I am using unordered_map and I am unable to declare a vector of pointers as value. I have the following declarations:

```
//file test.h

#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

struct Record
{
    char **data;
};

typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<Record*> > MAP;
typedef std::pair<std::string,std::vector<Record*> > PAIR;
```

I have included this header file in test.cpp, and When I compile using g++, I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:80: error: provided for ‘template<class T,   class Allocator> struct std::vector’
test.h:10: error: template argument 2 is invalid
test.h:10: error: template argument 5 is invalid
test.h:10: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

Any idea what this error means?

Comment: Is it possible that MAP is a macro defined somewhere in the code?

Comment: which line is causing the problem?

Comment: Please post a self-contained test-case. With your current code, one could say you are missing at least two essential header files.

Comment: I have changed MAP to something else but it still does not work

Comment: What is "something else"? Please follow @juanchopanza 's advice. This would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `vector` and `string` headers, needed for `std::vector` and `std::string` respectively.

You should include `utility` too, for `std::pair`. This may be included by `boost/unordered_map.hpp`, but you shouldn't rely on that.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
```